# Can I use jQuery easing with existing CSS mouseovers that use background-position?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, easing-functions, jquery-easing

I have a series of image mouseover links that change background-position when hovered.  Is it possible to use jquery easing with these links without changing my CSS3?  If so does anyone have any examples?

here is my code:

```
  <div id="bbnav">
  <a class="bbnav1" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav2" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav3" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav4" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav5" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav6" href="#"></a>
  <a class="bbnav7" href="#"></a>
  </div>

  .bbnav1:hover {background-position:     0px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav2:hover {background-position:  -159px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav3:hover {background-position:  -273px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav4:hover {background-position:  -422px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav5:hover {background-position:  -580px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav6:hover {background-position:  -658px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
  .bbnav7:hover {background-position:  -808px  -64px; cursor::pointer}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a scenario that mixed JavaScript easing with the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class.

The CSS3 specification outlines [transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).  These could be a solution to your problem.  However, they are not yet universally supported.